# Novel set on a distant planet, with creatures able to taste and smell through their feet upon the surface

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, space

I am trying to find a novel set on a distant planet with unusual life forms, including one kind that can "taste" and "smell" through their feet upon the surface.

It's almost as though the creatures are part plant and part animal.

Comment: Hi there! That's a bit terse at the moment; luckily, we have [an helpful guide on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028)! Please browse through it to see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in. Things such as what the cover looked like, what year it was published, etc, etc. The more info you can give us, the more likely you have to get an ID. Cheers :)

Comment: In the meantime, [one possibility](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85253/5930).

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it and continue to jog my memory.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't much to go on, but one example of a race of aliens that have chemosensory organs in their "feet" are the Czill from Jack Chalker's *[Midnight at the Well of Souls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_at_the_Well_of_Souls)*. They are flat, bipedal plants with paired brains in their feet.  They can taste and smell things on the ground, especially when they put out tendrils to absorb moisture.

They were depicted in *Barlowe's Guide to Extraterrestrials*:
[image: Czill]
(Oddly, however, they are *not* the aliens depicted on the original cover of the book, linked at its Wikipedia page above.)

The book has also been featured in other answers:

- [Looking for old book, SF, artificial world, different zones for different species that visitors "inhabit"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135337/looking-for-old-book-sf-artificial-world-different-zones-for-different-specie/)
- [Looking for a book where the planet is a device to rebuild the universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99584/looking-for-a-book-where-the-planet-is-a-device-to-rebuild-the-universe/)
- [Book series in which a world is divided into zones and people get transfigured when going from the hub to a zone](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143208/book-series-in-which-a-world-is-divided-into-zones-and-people-get-transfigured-w/)
- [Planet with hexagons with either magic or technology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3562/planet-with-hexagons-with-either-magic-or-technology/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the cheela in [The Dragon's Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg) taste things by crawling over them.