# Which book is it with a planet having animals which taste/ sense with their feet?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel

I need help identifying a book that I had read years ago. It's probably a children's book, which might be a part of a series.
The plot is set on a distant planet, with two species of animals if I remember correctly.
One of those has the ability to taste with their feet, and they use this as their primary sense organ. I may be misremembering this, but I think these animals are quadrupeds and are blind.
The other animal species is, I think a resident of canyons or chasms on the planet, but my brain may be muddling the story of this book with themes from The Time Machine.

Comment: [Andalites](https://animorphs.fandom.com/wiki/Andalite), in K.A. Applegate's Animorphs series (plus spinoffs), are quadrupeds who taste with their feet. They're far from blind, though, having four eyes instead of two, and I don't remember any other natives of their planet. Could that be what you're thinking of?

Comment: Also, the Hork-Bajir in the Animorphs series live in the canyons and chasms. The "Hork-Bajir Chronicles" is a book largely about an  Andalite on the Hork-Bajir homeworld, and the Hork-Bajir she befriends.

Comment: possible related : https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204669/novel-set-on-a-distant-planet-with-creatures-able-to-taste-and-smell-through-th/204693

Comment: It's a stretch, but [Cluster](https://www.amazon.com/Cluster-Piers-Anthony/dp/1497637686) by Piers Anthony has a race 'Polarian' who taste via their "feet", actually a ball they roll on.